# Will I mix up German and Norwegian if I learn them at the same time?

Tags: spoken-language

I speak Norwegian at B2 level, but I also want to learn German. Are they from the same language-family, will I start to mix up them if I start to learn German? Are they too similar?

Comment: The German StackExchange is the wrong place for this question. You should ask it here: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: ... or even better https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you are a native speaker of Japanese, Norwegian and German are extremely similar to you. If you are a native speaker of English, they are as far from each other as English and German are (or English and Norwegian are).

Comment: This is not primarily opinion-based, as there’s actual research regarding this topic. See https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-there-any-studies-which-address-the-effectiveness-of-studying-multiple-relat

Comment: This should be on https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/ as stated in the comments. (There is no migrate option for this here) As Philipp stated, it is not opinion-based. Please consider this meta article: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/community-moderation-robo-reviews-dont-help-anybody?cb=1